# Can OS specific general questions be asked in StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Q. How to turn your Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to a wifi hotspot?

Now I want to know if such kind of questions are welcome in Stackoverflow? It is a general question about a particular OS for which there might be resources in internet but I did not find any in StackOverflow. I call it general as general public will also benefit from such questions apart from programmers and developers.

Or should we post it in the specific sites in this case unix.stackoverflow.com (where I was not able to find any existing solutions and am not sure of the response)?

Comment: you can ask it on http://superuser.com

Comment: you should try [ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) for ubuntu related questions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That does not seem to be a programming question, rather an Ubuntu question. As such Stack Overflow is not the place to ask it. Perhaps http://www.askubuntu.com would be a better alternative. Have a read through their FAQ though.

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with programming, it is clearly off-topic for Stackoverflow. It would be on-topic as far as I know on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), and might also be on-topic on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 4):

[From SuperUser's FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software personal and home computer
>     networking
>
> ...then you’re in the right place to ask your
>   question!

Historically, SuperUser was created exactly for this purpose, to ask and answer this kind of questions which didn't have a place on Stack Overflow.

If the question is specific to Ubuntu, you can indeed also ask it on AskUbuntu. The question matches both those sites.

Comment: *Yes, I left out the "Is not about" part. Didn't want people to fall asleep before the end*