# Where to ask DOS operating system question about the command prompt?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know how to operate a DOS operating system.
Where should I ask networking and computer operating systems questions?

Comment: Can you please give some more information about your intended question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @gparyani I don't think that's the right duplicate. I mean, it doesn't even mention SuperUser, which would (usually) be the right choice if DOS would be replaced with Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can OS specific general questions be asked in StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143878/can-os-specific-general-questions-be-asked-in-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 6):

It will depend on the specific question, but it looks like a topic for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or the lesser known [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/). From their [tour](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Retrocomputing Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for vintage-computer hobbyists interested in restoring, preserving, and using the classic computer and gaming systems of yesteryear.

Both sites have quite a few MS-DOS questions already:

- https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos
- https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos

Please have a look at their help center ([Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)) before asking your question.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange sites require that you show prior research. A certain amount of prior knowledge is assumed.

So, if you are a complete beginner you should first learn the basics of DOS. Stack Exchange is not the place for that; instead, find a book or course on the subject.

After that, if you still have a problem, you can ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com). Be sure to search there first; maybe your question has already been asked and answered.

You also mention networking. We have [NetworkEngineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). The same advice applies here: Stack Exchange is **not** a place where we teach the basics; if you need to learn the basics of networking, there are plenty of websites about that already. If you have a specific question, that has not been asked yet on Network Engineering Stack Exchange, then you can ask it there.